# Why won't my Flutter Inspector panel dock to the right side of the IDE like the other tools?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I have tried every optional setting (dock pinned, dock unpinned, etc.) but can't get the Flutter Inspector to dock nicely on the right side of the IDE like the other tools (e.g. Flutter Outline).
Here's what Flutter Inspector looks like:
[image]

And here's what Flutter Outline looks like:

[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove Flutter Inspector from sidebar and attach it to sidebar again.

First, click on the gear icon on Flutter Inspector and select `Remove from Sidebar`.
Then, go to `View->Tool Windows->Flutter Inspector` and attach it to sidebar again.

It should reset the panel settings and fix your problem.